# How to let the user decide where to insert the newline in antlr?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I would like to know if there is a way to get the user to choose his programming style in ANTLR?

I would like the user can insert both style in the code. I've already tried to insert `\n?` in the code like:

```
ifstatement:
'if' '(' expr ')' '\n'?
'{'? '\n'? statements '\n'? '}'? '\n'?;  but I think it's a waste of time
```

---

```
//first style
if(...){
    ...
}
//second style
if(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Does your language have significant line breaks? Otherwise I'd just ignore line breaks altogether. On an unrelated note, the fact that the braces are optional (independently of each other no less) looks very wrong to me.

Comment: @sepp2k no it doesnt. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: As I said, my suggestion is to just skip newlines. You're already skipping other white space, right (at least there is no mention of spaces in the grammar you posted)? So just add `\n` to the list of characters you skip.

Comment: @sepp2k WS: [\n\r\t ]+ -> skip; Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.